# Why is the Heron's Formula taught in a different way?

Tags: geometry

In high school, I was taught Heron's Formula in this format: let $s$ denote semiperimeter of $∆ABC$ then $$[∆ABC] = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$ where the symbols have their usual meanings. I feel some 'awkward' in this formula. Firstly, it introduces a new variable $s$ though I can easily calculate the value of it. Secondly, it is efficient only with rational values. When we have irrational values, solving using conventional method might be too lengthy. For example, take $a = 5$, $b = \sqrt{73}$, $c = \sqrt{52}$. We cannot calculate the area in one line. (In my case, I encountered these values while solving an integer answer type question and seeing the 'roots' made me question 'Can irrational values result in an integer?' ) I tried rearranging the terms and got this: $$[∆ABC]=\boxed{\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{4b^2c^2 -(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2}}$$ This formula is useful because it helps to eliminate the square roots. But, is the original version of Heron's formula more beneficial?

Comment: I suppose it’s easier for school students to memorize the original version.

Comment: Does this work for all triples ? If not, the original version would have the advantage to be more universal.

Comment: If the EXACT value is required, the Heron-formula in the original version might be not optimal. But I always liked this version, one of the reasons was, as mentioned, that it is easy to memorize.

Comment: Standard version of the Heron's formula is explicitly symmetric. Yours version is not. Therefore I would prefer the first one.

Comment: I also find $s$ a bit of an unnecessary distraction. I prefer to write 
$$16\;|\triangle ABC|^2=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)$$
Notice that last three factors recall the aspects of the Triangle Inequality
$$a\leq b+c\qquad b\leq c+a\qquad c\leq a+b$$ Thus, a valid triangle yields non-negative factors, so that the calculated area itself is guaranteed to be a non-negative real. Conversely, one can show that a non-negative product requires non-negative factors. This establishes the non-negativity of the "Heron product" as a Litmus test for whether $a$, $b$, $c$ are sides of a valid triangle.

Comment: This question is opinion-based.

Comment: To the extent you're interested in pedagogical reasons favoring one form or another, [MathEducators.SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com) may be a good place to ask this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's not obvious that your formula is symmetric regarding sides. A student may wonder what is so special about side $a$, so one need to subtract it. The original formula is explicitly symmetric, and thus easy to memorize.
2. [Edit after Oscar Lanzi comment] Having terms like $(s-a)=\frac12(b+c-a)$ makes it obvious that once triangle inequality fails, the product becomes negative and the formula loses the sense.
3. Heron's formula for triangle is a special case of [Brahmagupta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_formula) for area of cyclic quadrilateral, where $d=0$:
   $$
   A={\sqrt  {(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}}.
   $$
   If students have learnt Heron's formula, teacher can expand their knowledge with little extra mental efforts.
4. Regarding your note

> When we have irrational values, solving using conventional method might be too lengthy.

Counterpoint, if we have rational or integer values, then your formula is also not optimal for calculations. With $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=4$, I can do this in my head:
$$
A = \frac14\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)},
$$
while yours is trickier.

// Btw, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#History), your variant of formula is what was discovered by Chinese mathematicians.

Comment: Good point about triangle inequality!

Comment: @OscarLanzi: I also find the multiplied-out version helpful (but you're missing coefficients of $2$ on the mixed terms). The fact that all lengths appear with even powers is especially convenient in coordinate geometry, since it means the square root in the Distance Formula won't cause algebraic headaches (which isn't obvious from the factored form).

Comment: If we put in $s=(a+b+c)/2$ and multiply everything out, we get another symmetric form for the area =$(1/4)\sqrt{2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2−a^4−b^4−c^4}$. This kills all radicals when the sides are square roots, but it obscures the role of the triangle Inequality as necessary for a real area.